# Cannot find CaseArticle in Object Manager

Tags: knowledge

I'm working on Knowledge Articles at the moment and unable to find the CaseArticle junction object in Object Manager. Is this hidden or do I need to edit some kind of permission for this to be visible?

Answer (score -1):

The Junction object is [Linked Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=wo_linked_article_fields.htm&type=5)

Also, make sure the user is a Knowledge User(Knowledge User checkbox is turned on user)

Comment: I dont believe that is correct. A [LinkedArticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_linkedarticle.htm) is associated to WorkOrder. A [CaseArticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casearticle.htm) is associated to CaseId. They are different junction objects.

Comment: Upvote Reason - LinkedArticle and CaseArticle are two different objects. I added field on LinkedArticle and refernced it in CaseArticle update call, it fails due to invalid field.